# Dictionaries and files

Tags: python, file, function, dictionary, return

I am confused on how to do this homework assignment we are suppose to add a class with className to the classes dictionary and return True if 
it was added or False if it is already in the dictionary. Note that the classes dictionary has 
className for key and grade for value.

This is what I have.

```
def addClass(classes, className, grade):
    classes = {}
    if className not in classes:
        classes[className]=course
    else:
        print("That class already exists.")
```

Another question is that This function reads in a file containing class names and grades, which are separated by a ':' (colon). The contents of the report card are added to the classes dictionary. This must call the function addClass. Additionally, must incorporate error handing -> if a class and grade are not separated by a colon, then ignore that line and print out an error message. See bottom of write-up for an example of a file.

I have no idea how to do this one so any help would be great!

```
importReportCard(classes,filename="reportcard.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, you simply need to return something:

```
def addClass(classes, className, grade):
    if className not in classes:
        classes[className]=course
        return True
    else:
        print("That class already exists.")
        return False
```

also, i removed the `classes = {}` because you already supply the dictionary when you call your function.

Comment: but how would i define grade?